# Count Row Divisible by 4

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database for example 1 Lab ID  =  15 Sample each sample have 4 items or more than 4.

example data

```
Lab ID    Sample ID    Test ID  /each test ID have 
1         16           32            test a     
1         16           32            test b
1         16           32            test c     total test 4
1         16           32            test d

1         17           33            test a
1         17           33            test b
1         17           33            test c     total total 5
1         17           33            test d
1         17           33            test e

1         18           34            test a
1         18           34            test b
1         18           34            test c    total total 5
1         18           34            test d
1         18           34            test e

1         19           35            test a
1         19           35            test b
1         19           35            test c    total total 5
1         19           35            test d   
1         19           35            test e

1         20           36            test a
1         20           36            test b    total total 4
1         20           36            test c
1         20           36            test d
```

How to counts the number of each test in Test ID which is not divisible by 4?

Output must be 3.

Comment: mysql xammp database

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Or you just need the answer ... :/

Comment: I tried it but not getting the right result

Comment: You changed the whole question from "where test ID is not divisible by 4" to "where the number of entries per test ID is not divisible by 4". This is very different and you should have made this a new separate question.

Comment: if this question has been solved, it should be marked as solved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, yes it solved, how to marked as solved? I'm just new here sorry

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I believe you just have and *Welcome to Stack*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MODULO` operation, [`MOD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

```
select count(*)
from `your_table_name`
where MOD(`Test ID`, 4) <> 0;
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: select count(test_id) from test_kind where labid = 16 and test_id % 4 = 0 

i try this one.. im Getting 12 .. w/c the answer must be 6 sir..

Comment: I have 6 Sample ID with more than 4 Test ID.

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten : It should be `not equal to(<>)` right? `select count(test_id) from test_kind where labid = 16 and test_id % 4 <> 0;`

Comment: I think i delivered it wrong. for example 

TEST ID I ROWS

1  = 4 rows
2  = 5 rows
3  = 5 rows
4  = 4 rows
5  = 5 rows

on your QUERY is getting the modulo of test it number. I want to output the rows per TEST ID

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten : I am not able to understand your problem. Please edit your question with proper description, sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try query below

```
    select count(*) from     
    (  select count(*) from example a
       where MOD(`Test_ID`, 4) <> 0 group by Test_ID) b
```

Aliases `a` and `b` need to be used because of error in SQL

```
 #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

So you can change aliases if want.

Working SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c80715)

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL-databases support the modulo operator.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM yourTable WHERE yourColumn % 4 != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%` operator for this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE `Test ID` % 4 <> 0;
```

Comment: That can not be. Can you prove it?

Comment: select count(test_id) from test_kind where labid = 16 and test_id % 4 = 0 

i try this one.. im Getting 12 .. w/c the answer must be 6 sir..

Comment: I have  1 lab id w/ 6 Sample ID with more than 4 Test ID.

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten, thats strange... why are you using `= 0` when in my answer there is `<> 0`???

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the test inside of the COUNT if you have other statistics to retrieve in the same query:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(MOD(`Test ID`, 4), 0))
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want only Test ID then try this

```
SELECT A.`Test ID` FROM(SELECT `Test ID`,COUNT(1) AS COUNT FROM TABLE GROUP BY `Test ID`) AS A WHERE A.COUNT % 4<>0;
```

if you want Test ID with Count then try this

```
SELECT A.`Test ID`,A.COUNT FROM(SELECT `Test ID`,COUNT(1) AS COUNT FROM TABLE GROUP BY `Test ID`) AS A WHERE A.COUNT % 4<>0;
```

if you want only count of total Test ID's which has not four test then try this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS COUNT FROM(SELECT `Test ID`,COUNT(1) AS COUNT FROM TABLE GROUP BY `Test ID`) AS A WHERE A.COUNT % 4<>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired by using **modulo** function

MOD(FieldName, Number)

The following query will help you to get the desired result:-

select count(*)
from `your_table_name`
where MOD(`Test ID`, 4) <> 0;

Here MOD(`Test ID`, 4) is checked that it should not be equal to 4